# Vueling baggage check policy

Tags: luggage, luggage-storage, vueling

The boarding pass reads:

"Your reservation includes a checked bag. Go to the check-in counters to check in your baggage."

I took the baggage to the gate instead (my bad, I understand) and was charged an extra €60 just to cross the gate and give the luggage to the airline staff which got the luggage to the plane. I was told then I would be reimbursed (Which I can't prove, but did happen).

I've exchanged over a dozen emails with them and they won't refund the money.

Fortunately I paid the original baggage allowance with a credit card.

I understand I made a mistake but it was never told I would have to pay, I asked the airline where was this information posted and they refused to answer. Also, I told I'd get reimbursed.

Do I have grounds to take it up with them and get a refund? Any other options?

Comment: Maybe a (credit card) chargeback?

Comment: Well, as they say, "you pays your money and you takes your chances." These carriers are famous for their prodigious add-on fees.

Comment: In my opinion, no, you don’t have much grounds, other than the fact they told you would be refunded, though I’m not sure I understand why they told you that.

Comment: @jcaron very common in Spain, they just wanted to move things along, make it the next person's problem.

Comment: @Leaderboard that's next move I have in mind.

Comment: What were the size and weight of your bag? How much did you pay for the checked bag initially? What type of fare was your ticket?

Comment: @jcaron regulation size bag, paid €40 each way, basic fare

Comment: Don't do a credit card chargeback, they could get a court judgment and debt collectors and you'll end up paying a lot more. And you can guarantee they're a lot more familiar with the legal procedure than you are. Even if they did say you would get a refund, you can't prove it, and it's possible you were mistaken, or they said something less definite like "you might be able to get a refund". If you're flying with a budget airline you absolutely must follow the conditions, or pay extra for a real airline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Vueling Conditions of Carriage](https://www.vueling.com/en/customer-services/conditions-of-carriage) tells us, in section 8, under “Hand luggage”:

> At the boarding gate, any hand luggage that does not comply with the Carrier's conditions of carriage, i.e.:
>
> a) **it has not been checked in at the check-in desk**, in the cases allowed (mentioned above);
>
> b) you have not added the service or selected the fare that includes hand luggage on board;
>
> c) it exceeds the stipulated amount, weight or size;
>
> will be removed and placed in the hold, at an additional cost.

(Emphasis mine).

“Additional cost” links to [this page](https://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/supplementary-service-rates), which states:

> Checked bag - up to 10 kg and max. 55x40x20 cm (cabin bag): Between 60.00  and 75.00  per passenger at boarding gate
>
> A checked case of up to 25 kg: From 110.00  per bag at the boarding gate

The condition for the checked luggage you paid for in advance was to drop it at check-in/bag drop, where there is an optimised process to handle it and get it to the plane. At the gate it needs a lot more manual processing and handling (for which the ground service handler used by Vueling certainly charge them a hefty fee).

Depending on its size, it could have been considered “large” cabin luggage (60 euros), but then put in the hold anyway due to lack of space, or as checked luggage (110 euros).

Comment: Thanks for that. The airline didn't provide this when prompted.

Comment: @hikizume I'll wager that Vueling's Terms & Conditions were made available to you (perhaps in small print, more likely in a link) when you purchased the ticket.